# Python - Smallest value with no limits presets WHILE loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm kinda new at coding and I've been facing some difficulties at the moment to record the smallest value in a WHILE loop. For example:

```
n = int(input('N: ')
smallest = n
while n != 0:
    if n < smallest:
        smallest = n
    n = int(input('N: ')
```

I know that this will save the smallest number until the user inputs 0. But, sometimes I have tried applying this method in other exercises like the following case:

```
smallest = 99999999999999
acu_total = 0
p = int(input('Price: $'))
while p != 0:
    while p < 0:
        p = int(input('ERROR - Price cannot be negative: $'))
    if p == 0:
        print('\nPROGRAM ENDED')
    else:
        q = int(input('Quantity: '))
        while q < 1:
            q = int(input('ERROR - Quantity cannot be less than 1: '))
    total = p * q
    acu_total += total
    if q < smallest:
        smallest = q
    p = int(input('\nPrice: $'))
print('\nTotal: ', acu_total)
print('Smallest: ', smallest)
```

I can't get to find how to apply the same method in this kind of exercises. I'm trying to avoid presetting the value of SMALLEST with a ridiculously high number but if I try placing the value of of smallest = q inside the while, every time the code runs it'll save the value of the last number entered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just an other way to solve this issue other than setting smallest to infinite: Initialize it as `None` and do

```
if smallest is None or q < smallest:
```